# como faço para funcionar a função exportEnable no canvas js no internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

tenho esse código abaixo que me mostra um gráfico porém no IE não funciona a função exportEnable e nem animationEnabled no chrome funciona porém quando eu chamo a pagina no modal a altura da tela fica curta no chrome e no IE com o modo de compatibility view settings habilitado funciona as funções porém com altura da janela pequena, no modal estou utilizando uma biblioteca do bootstrap e dentro do modal estou chamando um iframe que trás as páginas com o gráfico

codigo canvas js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
            //title:{
                //text: "Failure Overall - WK5" ,
                //fontColor: "red"
            //},
            //subtitles:[{
                //text: "<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");?>",
                //fontColor: "black"
            //}],
            colorSet: "greenShades",

             animationEnabled: true,
             exportEnabled: true,
             responsive: true,
            axisY: {
                tickThickness: 1,
                lineThickness: 1,
                gridThickness: 1
            },
                axisX: {
                tickThickness: 1,
                lineThickness: 1,
                labelFontSize: 11,
                interval: 1,
                labelFontColor: "Peru",
                labelAngle: -30
            },
            dataPointWidth: 40,
            data: [
            {        
                type: "column",
                indexLabelFontFamily: "arial",
                indexLabelFontColor: "black",
                //showInLegend: true,
                //legendText: "Total Failure: <?php echo $total;?>",
                dataPoints: [
                    <?php echo substr($linhaASM,0,-1);  ?>
                ]
            },
        {        
            type: "line",     
            //lineThickness: 4,
            indexLabelFontFamily: "arial",
            indexLabelFontColor: "black",
            //**Try various lineThickness values **//
            dataPoints: [
                    <?php echo substr($linhaPKG,0,-1);  ?>  
            ]
        }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();
    }

</script>
```